# Shorthand declaration of long generic collection types

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have looked at a lot of example c# generic code and remember seeing a syntactic declaration trick that created an alternative shorthand type for a long generic dictionary type. Mixing C# and C++ it was something like:

```
typedef MyIndex as Dictionary< MyKey, MyClass>;
```

This then allowed the following usage:

```
class Foo
{
    MyIndex _classCache = new MyIndex();
}
```

Can someone remind me which C# lanaguage feature supports this?

Comment: Wow, this is something I just would not do. C# doesn't have macros for a reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's this, another form of the [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), used to define an alias.

```
using MyClass = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>;

namespace MyClassExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var instanceOfDictionaryStringInt = new MyClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Rob and others. Next time I am in an interview I will know that it is called a using alias. Answer now baked into my code.

Comment: Forgot to say I think the alias (using) should be declared within an application namespace region.

Comment: I tried declaring it inside namespace MyClassExample and using in another file which does "using MyClassExample" but the alias "MyClass" is NOT recognized?

Comment: @Meryan, aliases are treated the same as other `using` directives and are scoped to the file in which they appear (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#remarks)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how its done

```
using Test = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string>;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test myDictionary = new Test();
            myDictionary.Add(1, "One");
        }

    }
}
```